# Getting HTTP 404 error in Spring login

Tags: spring

Error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /DemoTask/
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.90

Code:

```
import com.demo.bean.Login;

@Controller
public class LogController {
    
    @RequestMapping({ "/login" })
    public String showHome(@ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {
        String name = login.getUname();
        String password = login.getUpass();

        if ((name.equals("hello")) && (password.equals("hello"))) {

            return "redirect:admin.do";
        }

        return "login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping({ "login" })
    public String showLogin() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Restcontroller details here. how is the request mapping configured in the controller

Comment: @RamanathanGanesan I have added my Controller details below

Comment: How are you calling the /login endpoint? And please specify the complete error that you're getting.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found


Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.


Apache Tomcat/7.0.90

Answer (score 0):

Ambigious Request Mapping for the uri ***"login"***.
Added request type to mapping as below

```
@Controller
public class LogController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showHome(@ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {
        String name = login.getUname();
        String password = login.getUpass();

        if ((name.equals("hello")) && (password.equals("hello"))) {

            return "redirect:admin.do";
        }

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLogin() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```